# AngularJS reverse routes

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way of getting the URL attached to a controller by the $routeProvider other than hard-coding the URL in the href attribute? If you modify the routes in the $routeProvider you have to modify all the hard-coded URLs in the templates which is not very efficient.

For example the Django Framework provides the "[reverse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)" utility function and "[url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)" template tag which given the "controller" (view function) and the URL parameters it returns the associated URL.

Comment: I'm not sure about $routerProvider, but if you use ui-router rather than the built-in Angular router, you can use $state.href, explained at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statehrefstateorname--params--options

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to do this but you can use [angular.named-routes](https://github.com/airtonix/angular-named-routes/) which provides reverse urls.

$routeProvider:

```
$routeProvider.when("/product/:id/:slug", {
    templateUrl: "/product.html",
    controller: "ProductController",
    name: "product-detail"
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

$scope

```
{product: {id: 1, name: "Awesome Product", slug: "awesome-product"}}
```

Doing a reverse from template:

```
<a data-named-route="product-detail" data-kwarg-id="{{ product.id }}" data-kwarg-slug="{{ product.slug}}">{{ product.name }}</a>
```

Should turn into:

```
<a href="/product/1/awesome-product">Awesome Product</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there is no built-in way to do this. Because even if a controller may be bound to the $routeProvider, it doesn't has to. A way to achieve it is to make all your Controllers inherit from a BaseController. This BaseCtrl inject into the scope the property "currentUrl".

```
  myApp.controller("BaseCtrl" ,function ($scope, $location) {

  });

  myApp.controller("AnyCtrl" ,function ($scope, $location) {      

  //inherit from base
  $injector.invoke(function ($controller) { $controller('BaseCtrl', {$scope: $scope}); });

  });
```

Another way to achieve it is to "pollute" (thus not a very good idea but will work) the $rootScope by changing $rootScope.currentUrl each time the route has changed. Because all scopes inherit from $rootScope, the variable $scope.currentUrl will always be available and up to date into any view you want.